# How to customise cost function in Scikit learn's model？

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

For example, when I have a problem that false negative should be penalised more, how can I incorporate that requirement in the algorithm such as SVM?

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html

Comment: Please kindly refer to the answer of the link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67897092/7701181

Comment: This is possible in scikit-learn only if you use `GridSearchCV` and `cross_val_score`, not for a single model trained with the `.fit` method

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways in which you can achieve your desired result:

- Implement the [make_scorer function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) from Scikit learn
- Make modification to the class_weight argument

In regards to your SVM question take a look at the below code:

```
 class sklearn.svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='rbf', degree=4, gamma=0.0,
 coef0=0.0, shrinking=True, probability=False, tol=0.003,
 cache_size=300, class_weight=None, verbose=False, max_iter=-1,
 random_state=None)
```

In the above example, the class_weight function can be changed to 'auto' or you can pass dictionary values which have the user-defined class weights.